# emacs dap-debug with python on mac: Debug session process exited with status: exited abnormally with code 1

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I'm unable to run the dap-debug command. After running it and selecting one of the autogenerated configs in the minibuffer, I get this error:

```
Debug session process exited with status: exited abnormally with code 1
```

Here is my config:

```
(use-package dap-mode
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq dap-python-debugger 'debugpy)
  (dap-auto-configure-mode)
  (require 'dap-python))
```

This seems to be specific to MacOS because it works on my linux machine.

Comment: Difficult to guess, since the error message you provided isn't really informative. In [this ticket](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/635) more info is given in a somewhat similar situation, so probably you could also find it (note sterr buffer mention).

Comment: I saw that and actually attempted to use the config mentioned as the solution but it didn't help. I think their issue is a different thing because there's reference to "opening up a lot of windows and then closing them all again". In my situation the debugger doesn't launch at all, and only the very vague and short error message is produced, no reference to "sterr". I did go so far as to redirect stderr from emacs to a file but nothing was produced.